# What is the process for becoming a FIDE rated chess player?

Tags: rating, fide

I am new to chess. I read about **FIDE** so my question is: How can I
can play in a FIDE tournament or become a FIDE-rated player?

Is there any online process for that, or something else? Right now I only know
about FIDE and not much about their process. Someone told me about FIDE but he was not very clear about them.

Answer (score 11):

> How can I can play in a FIDE tournament

In exactly the same way you would a non-FIDE rated tournament. First enter. Then play.

> How can I can become a FIDE-rated player?

To get a FIDE rating you need to score at least one draw against at least 5 FIDE rated opponents in FIDE rated tournaments with a performance rating of at least 1000 over a period of not more than 26 months.

Comment: I have not kept up to date, but in the United States, as recently as the 1990s, FIDE-rated tournaments were hard to find. Most tournaments I ever heard about were USCF-rated only, for some reason. U.S. chess players seemed to have the impression that FIDE ratings were a European thing. I wonder if that is still true.

Comment: @brain how we can know about fide tournaments. is this any online process, website?

Comment: @PankajBisht FIDE rated tournaments have to be registered with FIDE at least 7 days in advance by the national federation and when registered they immediately appear on the FIDE website. For instance the tournaments for India are here - https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=IND. There is a search facility on the page which allows you to select other federations.

Comment: how did the 1st FIDE rated people get their ratings since i guess no one really had FIDE ratings? awarded like base step in mathematical induction?

Comment: @BCLC The process was described by Arpad Elo in his book "Rating of Chess Players - Past and Present". Basically, the results of the players against each other is calculated and re-calculated until there's no more significant changes.  Then the calculated ratings are placed (collectively) at some preconceived level -- perhaps to become comparable to some other rating system. After that, it is business as usual.

Comment: @user30536 What? I mean the very 1st players to get FIDE ratings. Like did everyone just start 1200?

Comment: @ BCLC:  If you want the details (and there are details), please read Arpad Elo's book.

Answer (score 4):

To get a FIDE rating, all you need to do is play in a few FIDE rated tournaments. Many big open tournaments with lots of players are FIDE rated, so those would be a good bet. You can find these tournaments by just searching on Google "Chess Tournaments in x" where x is the region you live.

There is no online sign-up process necessary. Once you play 9 FIDE-rated games and score at least 3/9 (unless the rules have changed) then you'll have a FIDE rating.

Comment: And realistically speaking, if you are a beginner, scoring 3/9 in a big open tournament is unlikely at least for the tournaments I know.

Answer (score 1):

The International Chess Federation (FIDE) has several types of FIDE rating. The easiest FIDE rating to get is the online FIDE rating.  For that purpose, FIDE has a website that is relative cheap because you only need to pay 25 Euros per year (25-30 U.S. Dollars).

These are the most important links:

https://chessarena.com/?popup=registration

https://chessarena.com/